# WPF ListView Insert Item at Given Position when using ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a ListView who's ItemsSource is set to an ObservableCollection.  The user can sort and filter the ListView, done by using the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView and altering the ICollectionView Filter and SortDescriptions.

When the user right-clicks a row, they can add an item to the collection.  I want this new row to appear below the row right clicked.  So far all the methods I've found for something like this are done with ListView.Items which I can't use because I'm setting the ItemsSource property.

Comment: typo? "soft and filter" = sort and filter?

Does this mean you want the newly added item to appear out of sort order?  In other words, regardless of where it *would* have sorted to, it should always appear after the right clicked row?

Comment: typo corrected - ty
yes, the new item will be out of order (until the user sorts again).  This is so the new item appears in the UI and not out of view and the user thinks it wasn't added.

Comment: To solve this I've added a new property to my objects, and use it to "bake" the current sort order, add my new item with this property set to where I want it to appear, then setting the SortDescriptions to this new property.  It has the desired result, but it seems like there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

Try ObservableCollectionName.Insert((ListViewName.SelectedIndex + 1), ItemToInsert)

Comment: When using the DefaultView for sorting, the ListView's order will not match the order of the underlying collection.